# PowerShell script as a task scheduler doesn't work correctly

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

When I run the task scheduler it gives me a (0x1) error code. Basically this is to copy all files on the desktop and place them in Google Drive.

Backup1.ps1

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Backup2.ps1'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "BackUP Google Drive" -Description "Google Drive Backup"
```

Backup2.ps1

```
Copy-Item "C:\Users\User\Desktop\*" -Destination "G:\My Drive\BackUp" -Recurse -Force
```

The Backup2.ps1 works 100% of the time when running it under PowerShell alone. The problem is that the task scheduler isn't completing the task due to the (0x1) error.

Comment: `0x1` isn't an error code, it's an exit code indicating that in one way or another, it could not do what it's expected to. If you select your task in the Task Scheduler then click the "History" tab and double click the event, it will likely give you a more helpful message. The only thing I can think of based on what's been provided is that the path to the script might have a space in it, and since you're not putting the path in quotes, it would treat the path as two separate positional parameters.

Comment: Maybe G: isn't mapped.  You should be able to do `backup.ps1 > logfile`  I'm assuming the executionpolicy is remotesigned at least.

Comment: This worked out after looking at this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370547/windows-scheduled-task-succeeds-but-returns-result-0x1
This is something that Microsoft should fix.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: In the post Andreas said

"I have seen this problem multiple times while scheduling Powershell scripts with parameters on multiple Windows servers. The solution has always been to use the -File parameter:

Under "Actions" --> "Program / Script" Type: "Powershell"
Under "Add arguments", instead of just typeing "C:/script/test.ps1" use -File "C:/script/test.ps1"
Happy scheduling!"

Comment: My previous settings were "program/script" Powershell.exe "Add arguments" C:/script/test.ps1